# searchByQuery function returns only 10 rows

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

Why does this search returns only 10 rows, it should return more?

```
    $laws_y = Law::searchByQuery([
    ],
        [
            "group_by_law_year" => ["terms" => ['field' => "law_year"]]
        ]);
```

And every other searchByQuery with a first parameter null and second as aggregate returns only 10 rows?

Comment: 10 is default limit in elasticsearch. you can use size parameter to increase the number of results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch returns 10 records by default Use `size` and set the limitation to something that makes sense to you.

**Edit:**

For handling a large amount of records - see elasticsearch's *[scan and scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scan-scroll.html)* approach.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to do that